# git clone in shell script using credentials from Jenkins

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to clone a repo in a server using credentials stored in Jenkins and I am performing certain operations on that repo.

```
pipeline {
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        timestamps()
    }
    parameters {
        string(name: 'FILENAME', defaultValue: 'tmp', description: 'Enter the file name that needs to be copied')
        string(name: 'DB_NAME', defaultValue: 'tmp_db', description: 'Enter the database name that needs to be created')
        string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: '1', description: 'Enter the DB name version')
        choice(name: 'RUN', choices: 'Migrate Data', description: 'Data migration')
    }
    agent {
        node { label 'myserver' }
    }
    triggers {
        pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clean & Clone') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
                git(branch: 'jenkinsfilr-branch',
                        credentialsId: 'lsdeploy-github',
                        url: 'https://github.com/xyz')
            }
        }
        stage('Run the shell script On-prem'){
            steps {
                git(branch: 'progress',
                        credentialsId: 'lsdeploy-github',
                        url: 'https://github.com/abc')
                 }
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'env-on-prem', targetLocation: '.env')]) {
                    sh  '''
                            bash -x ./ops/database-migration/migrate.sh ${FILENAME} ${DB_NAME} ${VERSION}
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The migrate.sh contains operations performed on the `abc` folder (cloned from https://github.com/abc) while the migrate.sh resides in `xyz` repo (cloned from https://github.com/xyz). In this case, since abc repo is cloned latest, jenkins throws an error that it can't find the migrate.sh script. Is there any way to avoid this error? I tried to perform `git clone --branch progress https://github.com/abc` in the migrate.sh script, but it asks me for credentials. I tried the other way, so that I can store the credentials in Jenkins and also clone the repo. Any help?

Comment: Can you expose the credentials in an environment variable?  If so, you can use [this entry from the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials-environment).

Comment: You say that your pipeline throws an error saying that it can't find migrate.sh, but then you say later that when you add a new line to migrate.sh, then you are asked for credentials. How do you manage to run migrate.sh if the file isn't found?

Comment: I think what you need to do is `cd` to the `xyz` directory before you run the migrate.sh script. Or alternatively you could `cp` the migrate.sh script to your working directory, and then run it.

Comment: Thank you @ShaneBishop, this was so simple and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @shane Bishop, here is the solution that finally worked

```
pipeline {
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        timestamps()
    }
    parameters {
        string(name: 'FILENAME', defaultValue: 'tmp', description: 'Enter the file name that needs to be copied')
        string(name: 'DB_NAME', defaultValue: 'tmp_db', description: 'Enter the database name that needs to be created')
        string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: '1', description: 'Enter the DB name version')
        choice(name: 'RUN', choices: 'Migrate Data', description: 'Data migration')
    }
    agent {
        node { label 'myserver' }
    }
    triggers {
        pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clean & Clone') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
                git(branch: 'jenkinsfilr-branch',
                        credentialsId: 'lsdeploy-github',
                        url: 'https://github.com/xyz')
            }
        }
        stage('Run the shell script On-prem'){
            steps {
                sh 'cp ./ops/database-migration/on-prem/migrate.sh ./'
                git(branch: 'progress',
                        credentialsId: 'lsdeploy-github',
                        url: 'https://github.com/abc')
                 }
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'env-on-prem', targetLocation: '.env')]) {
                    sh  '''
                            bash -x migrate.sh ${FILENAME} ${DB_NAME} ${VERSION}
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```